# flutter pub get command get dependencies I didn't put it in pubspec.yaml

Tags: android, flutter, dart, dependencies, pubspec.yaml

`i try to delete the cache of dependencies and i get same problem and some time call dependencies  which i use it in another project like firebase or another dependencie. i notied that happen after the update of flutter sdk.`

this image what i have in pubspec.yaml file and i did not have any dependencies in it
[image: my spec.yaml file]

Comment: These are for the SDK (project) itself.

Comment: is that normal? because i see that after i update flutter sdk

Comment: Yap, it is, if you notice the package's name you can see default package like `async` ,`flutter_lints`, Cupertino...etc

Comment: Please do not post images of code or errors. Text is preferred so that we can try to reproduce the problem without having to re-type everything and your question can be properly indexed or read by screen readers.

Answer (score 0):

try use flutter clean in terminal
or delete the file manually his name pubspec.lock